# Localhost and SQL Server setup

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, iis

It is my third on with SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio and IIS. I managed some how to set up my localhost, make databases etc. In IIS my 2 projects is registered as project_1.local and project_2.local. When I go to my localhost:8080 I get the pages cannot be displayed. Normally when I use MAMP I can go to my localhost, and get a list of my projects.

Why do I get the error the page cannot be displayed? Isnt it possible to get my projects as a list instead, like I can on my "normal" MySQL MAMP localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open your site via iis? open IIS management and try to browse to you local site with the url that display in the IIS. Maybe you are missing a sub domain that your site is use.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to open your project into sql server and run it ? instead of server of mamp